# I cannot include winsock2.h using MinGW

Tags: qt, mingw, winsock2

I'm using Qt Creator with MinGW.

I included "windows.h" and compile it, but it failed. Errors are below:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/windows.h:98:0,
             from util/IdleDetector.h:8,
             from service\PresenceService.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/winsock2.h:771:22: error:     expected unqualified-id before string constant
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/winsock2.h:1034:95: error: expected identifier before string constant
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/winsock2.h:1034:95: error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant
```

I thought that the MinGW path was missing, but that's not the case. How can I fix this?

Comment: What are the lines 771 and 1034 of you winsock2.h? Have you tried including winsock2.h explicitely before windows.h?

Comment: There are no string constant in those lines. Please show your complete compile command, and check if you `#define`s. These two lines would be invalid if `GROUP` is defined to a string literal.

Comment: I solved it with editing GROUP. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Is `windows.h` pulling in `winsock.h` or `winsock2.h`?  The two are not compatible with each other.  `winsock2.h` is meant to replace `winsock.h`, and as such re-declares a lot of things that `winsock.h` already declares.  If `winsock2.h` is included before `winsock.h`, then `winsock2.h` silently disables `winsock.h` and all is fine.  But if `winsock.h` is included before `winsock2.h`, all kinds of errors can occur.